# Qt disable move window

Tags: qt, window

I have a QMainWindow with this flag :

```
this->setWindowFlags(Qt::SubWindow);
```

How do to forbid the window moving, and this, keeping this window style ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a cross-os Qt way to achieve this when using the standard window controls.

You can try stuff like:

```
class Widget : public QWidget {
  Q_OBJECT

public:
  Widget()
    : fixed_pos_(QPoint(100, 100)) {
    setWindowFlags(Qt::SubWindow);
  }

  void SetFixedPos(const QPoint& pos) {
    fixed_pos_ = pos;
  }

protected:
  void moveEvent(QMoveEvent* ev) {
    if (ev->pos() != fixed_pos_)
      move(fixed_pos_);
  }

private:
  QPoint fixed_pos_;
};
```

These have a few issues like flicker, does not update until Mouse-release and so on that's also different per OS.

Most efficient way is to just make your Window a  [Qt::FramelessWindowHint](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qt.html#WindowType-enum) and render a titlebar yourself. That way you can pretty much do what you want when it comes to handling events on that titlebar.

Comment: qt docs specifically warn against calling move() from within moveEvent(): "Warning: Calling move() or setGeometry() inside moveEvent() can lead to infinite recursion."